# Which rush is better/faster in Starcraft II?

Tags: starcraft-2

In Starcraft 2 I've played as Protoss, and then recently switched to Terran.

As Protoss I loved to 4gate. In 90% of my 4gate-games I won, but in 10 percent the other player could barely hold it off.

After a while Protoss got boring, so I switched to Terran. Now my favourite type of rush is a 3rax all in push (Marines + SCVs with auto-repair as a shield).

My question is: Which of those two is better and/or faster than the other?

Comment: Which 3rax build are you doing? Some are pre 4 gate timings, some are the same time, some are slightly after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to agree with Sorean that this is a very subjective question since you have not  stated what you mean by "better".

If it is simply a matter of how effective it is...then that depends on the race you are playing against, and whether or not it is scouted.

Generally, though, I would say that 4-gate is "better" then marine/scv all-in since 4-gate really isn't an all-in build. Even if you manage to fail to kill the enemy, if you are able to deal quite a bit of damage, you can easily transition out of it and keep the pressure on the opponent for a good portion of the game. If you pull out of the attack after you realize it won't result in a win, you'll be all the stronger.

Honestly though, you should *not* be using all-in builds. At all. They are fine against lower level opponents, but once you start facing stronger players you're going to start losing more and more of your games, and if all you've been doing All-In cheeses, chances are your Micro/macro isn't the greatest. In other words, relaying on all-in builds is just going to hurt your game in the long-run.

Answer (score 0):

The question is too subjective into which one is better, what in particular are you asking to be better?

Which is more effective to kill the enemy?
Which is easier to fall back with in case the attack fails?

The answer to the faster question is that they are about equal timing. You can do both about the 7 minute mark into a game for some really early aggression. The thing about the 4gate is that there is a little more to fall back into (assuming a bit of army retention), but the Marine/SCV rush sacrifices a lot scvs to do so you don't have much of an economy to fall back on (not that 20-22 probes is a lot either).

Comment: Depending on the 3 rax variant, it can hit before the 5 minute mark, and in that case it is definitely faster than a 4 gate. 4 gate will also hit somewhere around the 6 minute mark generally, 7 minutes is late for a 4 gate.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm not really a terran player, and 7 minutes isn't that far off now with the recent nerf, although @ the 7 minute mark you should already have started the fight.